# Merging 3 bar charts into one stacked bar chart in Tableau

Tags: charts, bar-chart, tableau-api, stacked-chart

I am struggling to create stacked bar chart out of 3 separate bar charts in Tableau.

They suppose to look like this:
[image]

However, closest I've got is this in tableau
[image]
[image]

With other charts it's kinda easier with just dragging the values from rows into the y-axis and voala - stacked bar chart. Over here they just disappear, as I've removed them.
[image]

Hope anyone can shed light to my darkness with Tableau.

Comment: Have you tried Stack bar chart option from "Show Me" toolbar ?

Comment: Yes I did @KuldipMCA just messes it up. Ideally should be by dropping rows into each other as per the last screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close with your second Tableau screen shot.

From that configuration, move Measure Names from the Columns shelf to the Color shelf. Then you will get a colored bar for each measure on the Measure Values shelf, instead of a column for each measure.